# how to stop refetching data on page load using react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a page in react-js. I am using react query for fetching data from API. I want to store the data from the API for first time page visit in cache , after that always the data will be read from cache.

How to stop refetching of API request each time the browser tab changes or the page is reloaded ?

My component code is like this

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const QueryCache = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, isStale } = useQuery('yourQueryKey', async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  },
  );

  console.log({isFetching, isLoading})
  
//   console.log('Cached data:', data);

  console.log("isStale is ", isStale);

//   if (isLoading) {
//     // Data is being initially fetched
//     return <p>Loading...</p>;
//   }

//   if (isFetching) {
    
//       // Data is being refetched from the cache
//       return <p>Fetching updated data...</p>;
    
//   }
//   else {
//     return <p>Fetching updated data...</p>;
//   }

  // Render your component with the fetched data
  return (
    <div>
        {
            isLoading ? <>Loading...</> : 
                <>
                {
                   isFetching ? <>Notun data</> : <>Purono data</>
                }
                </>
            
        }
      <h1>Data:</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

export default QueryCache;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `staleTime: Infinity` and `cacheTime: Infinity` which will stop re-fetching on refresh and `refetchOnWindowFocus: false` to fetch data on tab changes.

Official Documentation: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/window-focus-refetching

**Modified Code:**

```
const QueryCache = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, error } = useQuery('yourQueryKey', async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  }, {
    staleTime: Infinity, // Data never gets stale
    cacheTime: Infinity, // Data remains in the cache indefinitely
  });
```

**=> Add `refetchOnWindowFocus: false` where you're creating an instance like this**

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false, // default: true
    },
  },
})

function App() {
  return <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>...</QueryClientProvider>
}
```

Let me know, If you've any other questions.

Comment: refetchOnWindowFocus: false,

this thing is working but on page reload the api request is made again